# Can a magnetic field have a orbital angular momentum

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

Is it possible to 'twist' a magnetic field? I am not referring to the electrical field but the actual magnetic field.

In OAM (orbital angular momentum) we can twist light waves and sound waves however can this be done for a magnetic field?

I've seen research on curving antennas to twist electromagnetic waves and it works, however does this effect translate the same for stationary magnetic fields?

If I twist a wire or curve a wire around a cylinder and apply a current will the resultant magnetic field have an orbital angular momentum? Or is the field only ever perpendicular to the wire?

If not how could you achieve a twisted magnetic field? Or does orbital angular momentum only apply to waves and not fields, which doesn't make sense to me as you can twist an EM wave which has a magnetic field?

Imagine a magnetic field twisted like the below image:

https://images.app.goo.gl/Yc62adZDmJxs3jM47

Comment: Not quite certain what it is exactly that you mean. Do you mean a magnetic field whose curl is non-zero ? In that case the current through a wire can produce such a [thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xmie.jpg).  Or maybe you mean something like a rotating bar magnet, which produces an electric dipole, analogous to quantum mechanical spin, but the roles of electricity and magnetism are reversed in a certain sense?

Comment: Roger Penrose came up with an idea that splitting an object in an ergosohere of a black hole would measure a loss of negative energy and provide it to the other half, recently this was proven in a Nature publication using sound waves. EM and Light waves move too fast for a feasible experiment to be carried out but twisted magnetic fields might be possible. My question is how would it possible to twist a magnetic field, I am unsure which bracket of the two propositions you supposed that this would fall into.

Comment: As a thought experiment imagine a twisted magnetic field moving through a rotating magnetic field, I want to measure if any gain is achieved the same way the sound experiment was conducted.

Comment: Are you talking about [magnetic helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_helicity)?

Comment: Helicity is more to do with self linkaged rather than twist. I will upload a picture of what I want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my question and as you can see it's a circular polarization or magnetic twist of the field, if a twisted magnetic field passing through a rotating magnetic field does not cause the same gain as the sound wave experiment then one would assume that something is at odds with the premise. The question is can such a twisted field be achieved if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solenoidal coil produces a magnetic field with no component that corresponds to "twist".  However, a straight wire carrying a current produces a magnetic field that it *all* "twist".  So, a solenoidal coil with a straight wire running along its axis will produce a twisted field that winds around the axis more or less as you describe.

[This article](https://theconversation.com/a-new-twist-on-fusion-power-could-help-bring-limitless-clean-energy-70324) has a layman's description of the tokamak fusion reactor which obtains a twisted field using a current along its axis.  The article also describes a stellarator reactor, which obtains a twisted field by distorting its toroidal coil.

However, this twist is not "orbital angular momentum".  Because there is no electric field in this configuration, there is no Poynting vector; and without the Poynting vector there is no EM field momentum and hence no angular momentum.

Comment: So you technically can't test the theory in this way? Re: My Comments.

Comment: The image your link leads to represents a propagating wave, not a static field.

Comment: Yes it was to illustrate what I wanted to achieve with a static field. I understand that you can't have angular momentum without the momentum (propagating wave) so in part that answers the question really, just making sure there isn't another way.

Comment: A propagating wave is not necessary for there to be field momentum. The Poynting vector is present in a stationary field if there are both E and H fields present, and if they are not parallel.

Comment: But the Poynting vector is just the cross product of the E and B fields? It's still going to be a flat (not twisted) magnetic field, have a look at the the gif in this link as an example https://brilliant.org/wiki/poynting-vector/

Comment: This, too, is a wave and not a static field.  It does not really relate to your question.  Do you want a twisted magnetic field, or do you want an *electromagnetic* field with angular momentum.  If the latter, you need both magnetic and electric fields.